# Iterating through table using jquery gives uncaught exception

Tags: jquery, html, web

when a user clicks on a cell in my table, i would like to iterate through my table's rows using the following:

```
var table = $(this).closest('table');

$(table+" tr").each(function(){
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
```

However i get the following error:

```
  uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`table` is an object, not a string. Try this:

```
$('tr', table).each(function() {
```

That will select `tr` elements which are descendants of the `table`.

You could also do this:

```
table.find('tr').each(function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

`table` is a jQuery collection.  Its toString method returns `[object Object]`.  When you concatenate a string to the object, it uses its toString to build the resulting string.

"[object Object] tr" is not a valid selector expression.  You can select descendants of a jQuery collection using `.find` or supplying the collection as the second argument to the jQuery method (a context for the selector).

Note that `.each` is not necessarily required for iteration.  It depends on what you need to do.

```
console.log($(this).closest("table").find("tr").text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3MDgy/1/